# Modal button OnClick event not firing in firefox

Tags: vb.net, button, modal-dialog, postback

I have this button inside a modal popup:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnOkay" Text="Invia" OnClick="btnOkay_Click" CssClass="btn btn-danger" UseSubmitBehavior="false" CausesValidation="true" OnClientClick="hideModal('{0}','{1}');" />
```

This is the "hideModal" function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       function hideModal(sender, e) {
           __doPostBack(sender, e);
       }
   </script>
```

The problem is this is working fine in Chrome, IE and Edge but not in Firefox (latest). What I can see is that it triggers a page postback before the btnOkay_click event is fired. How can I make it work just like in Chrome? Thanks

Comment: Do you get any errors or warnings in your development console?

Comment: @Jerodev I'm on developer console, I have 1 warning: Use of nsIFile in content process is deprecated and 1 error: Favicon at "http://localhost:64047/favicon.ico" failed to load: Not Found."  nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  location: "JS frame :: resource:///modules/FaviconLoader.jsm :: onStopRequest :: line 199"  data: no] but seems unrelated to my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that -for some reason- Firefox fails to execute the OnClientClick event, the solution was to get rid of it and replace it with **data-dismiss="modal"**, so my button is now like this:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnOkay" Text="Invia" OnClick="btnOkay_Click" CssClass="btn btn-danger" UseSubmitBehavior="false" CausesValidation="true" data-dismiss="modal" />
```

And it's working fine both on Chrome and Firefox